# PABX API Live Feed into Azure SQL

Tags: azure, pabx

I have a Azure SQL Database

The company has a PABX System that has an API that can provide call logs.

What would be the best resource in between to connect to the API, pull the call logs, and store it in Azure SQL DB in a staging table?

Afterwards I also need to call a SQL SP in the Azure DB to process the data to its final location.

I was thinking DataFactory, but not sure if Stream Analytics can work.

I would like to have a near real time feed of data from the API - perhaps every 5/10 seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid , but the triggers in ADF cannot be ran as frequent as 5/10 seconds. Moreover you should also check the threshold set on the API side , if you query it too soon they will throttle your request .

For stream analytics I do not think the API is can supported input .

Comment: There is known threshold on the API.

Comment: Also the ADF frequency is a concern to me. What do you mean by API Supported Input?